# Silverstripe 3.4.0 - Set Relationship between DataObject and Page - Data not saving to database

Tags: php, silverstripe, data-objects

I have a website with a project gallery, and there are subpages on the site dedicated to project types. I want to allow content managers to be able to select any project gallery items to display on any subpage of their choosing. A subpage can have many project gallery items, and a project gallery item can be display on one or more subpages.

I set up a `CheckboxSetField` on `Page.php` that displays a list of all project names from the `ProjectGalleryItem` DataObject. I have the checkbox list displaying in a separate tab on all subpages, but I cannot get any selected values to save--the checkboxes checked are automatically unchecked upon saving. No errors are showing in the log files or in the console.

I'm wondering if my relationships between `Page` and `ProjectGalleryItem` are incorrect?

Here is the code for `ProjectGalleryItem`:

```
<?php

class ProjectGalleryItem extends DataObject
{
    private static $db = array(
        'ProjectName'      => 'Varchar(250)',
        'ProjectDescription' => 'Text',
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'ProjectImage' => 'Image',
    );

    private static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'Pages' => 'Page',
    );

    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'ProjectName',
        'ProjectDescription',
    );
}

class ProjectGalleryItemAdmin extends ModelAdmin {
    private static $managed_models = 'ProjectGalleryItem';
    private static $url_segment = 'ProjectGalleryItems';
    private static $menu_title = 'Project Gallery Items';
}
```

And here is half of the `Page.php` file:

```
<?php

class Page extends SiteTree
{
    private static $db = array(
        'BannerH1' => 'HTMLText',
        'BannerSubH1' => 'HTMLText',
        'H1' => 'varchar(250)',
        'PageTitle' => 'varchar(250)',
        'BottomContent' => 'HTMLText',
        'StylizedList' => 'HTMLText',
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'BannerImg' => 'Image',
    );

    private static $has_many = array(
        'RotatorImages' => 'RotatorImage',
    );

    private static $many_many = array(
        'ProjectGalleryItems' => 'ProjectGalleryItem'
    );

    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextField("H1"), "Content");
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new HTMLEditorField("BannerH1"), "Content");
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new HTMLEditorField("BannerSubH1"), "Content");
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new HTMLEditorField('BottomContent', "Bottom Content"));
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new HTMLEditorField('StylizedList', "Stylized List"), "BottomContent");
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new TextField('PageTitle', 'Page Title'), 'MetaDescription');
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new UploadField('BannerImg', "Subpage Banner"), "Content");


        $metadataTab = $fields->findOrMakeTab('Root.Main.Metadata');
        $fields->removeByName('Metadata');
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $metadataTab);

        $gridFieldConfig = GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create();

        $gridFieldConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldBulkUpload());
        $gridFieldConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldSortableRows('SortOrder'));

        $gridFieldConfig->getComponentByType('GridFieldDataColumns')->setDisplayFields(array(
            // field from drawer class => label in UI
            'ID' => 'ID',
            'Title' => 'Title',
            'Thumbnail' => 'Thumbnail',
            'InternalURL.Link' => 'Internal URL',
        ));

        $gridfield = new GridField(
            "RotatorImages",
            "Rotator Images",
            $this->RotatorImages()->sort("SortOrder"),
            $gridFieldConfig
        );

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Rotator Images', $gridfield);

        $projects = DataObject::get('ProjectGalleryItem');

        if(!empty($projects))
        {
            $map = $projects->Map('ID', 'ProjectName');

            $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Projects',
            CheckboxSetField::create(
                $name = "Projects",
                $title = "Select Projects",
                $source = $map
            ));
        }

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like the issue is your form field name, it should match the name of the relation. The first parameter to `CheckboxsetField::create()` should be `ProjectGalleryItems`, not `Projects`.

Comment: That was the issue. Didn't even realize it :\